# Where(location) to install a Django project files on an Ubuntu Server, and permissions set

Tags: django, ubuntu, deployment, web-deployment

I need to go in production with a Django app on Ubuntu server.

Until now(for testing) I set the virtual environment and the project code, in the home directory of an user with sudo permissions(I saw in some tutorials doing this way).

But, I have a feeling that is not a good approach.

So, what are the best locations, and how to set security for Linux users ?

Answer (score -3):

Well, depends on the server that you're using, for eg:
if you're using apache to serve your project, you'd probably store it in /var/www/html...

But there's no set location to store your project files. Store them where you like, where it's easy for you to access them, and use virtualenv to encapsulate your libraries so that the system remains unaffected .

Comment: No, there is no good reason to put Django files in /var/www/html even for Apache, and in fact this is a security risk.